# Can you split your mount's movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat, mount

Since the **Players's handbook** only mentions that when you mount, the mount's initiative overlaps with yours, I'm wondering if can you move your mount (for example) 30 feet, attack and then move the remaining 30 feet?

Comment: Hello Spellcaster. This question seems to have been asked before. The short answer is: yes, you can split your mount's movement. But if the linked question doesn't answer your real question, you can always edit the post. Then it will get re-opened quickly.